# Add styling to active header - Ionic 3 / Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When the user is on the current page, I would like there to be the title of the page be underlined or the text change color - anything to show that the user is on that page. I am currently using lazy loading as a means to travel from page to page - with this in use I'm having to use modules for each page and I'm using a component for the header. The issue is how to figure out what page the user is on from the component.

header.html

```
<ion-header>

    <ion-navbar>
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>

    </ion-navbar>
    <div>

      <div (click)="openPageOne()">
        <h2>Page One</h2>
      </div>

      <div (click)="openPageTwo()">
        <h2>PageTwo</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
</ion-header>
```

app-header.ts

```
openPageOne() {
    this.nav.push(pageOne);
  }

  openPageTwo() {
    this.nav.push(pageTwo);
  }
```

then I place the app-header into a component module then import that module into my page module. Once it's there then I can place the header tag in the page html

Comment: In Angular you can do this with routing (RouterOutlet). But I believe you can't use router in Ionic, so you might check NavController. It might do the stuff you need. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#first

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use header component as a child component and @input,

header.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="{{header_info.headerColor}}">
  <button ion-button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title color="{{header_info.fontColor}}">
    {{header_info.title}}
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

In header.component.ts use input decorator

```
export class HeaderPage {
  @Input() header_info: {};
}
```

And from the parent component page you can pass or set header_info.
    From here you can set all properties according to parent page.
    Please check @input functionality.